# Quando "facto" passou a ser "fato"?

Tags: português-brasileiro, português-europeu, diferenças-transatlânticas, acordo-ortográfico

Actualmente, usa-se, em todo o Brasil, a palavra *fato* com o mesmo significado de *facto*, presente até hoje em Portugal e Angola, por exemplo.

A partir de que momento da história do Brasil essa mudança passou a vigorar? A mudança fonética (a remoção da consoante "c") veio com o passar do tempo após algum acordo ortográfico, ou já existia e foi a origem da mudança?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A grafia *facto* passou oficialmente a *fato* no Brasil com o [Formulário Ortográfico de 1943](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formul%C3%A1rio_Ortogr%C3%A1fico_de_1943#Texto_do_Formul.C3.A1rio_Ortogr.C3.A1fico_de_1943), que veio alterar a grafia de centenas (talvez milhares) de palavras, tal como já tinha acontecido em Portugal com a [Reforma Ortográfica de 1911](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reforma_Ortogr%C3%A1fica_de_1911).

O *c* foi eliminado da palavra *facto* no Brasil porque já não era pronunciado. Portugal e nos PALOPs é pronunciado e por isso manteve-se. As reformas ortográficas vieram aproximar a grafia à fala, nomeadamente, suprimindo consoantes mudas (mas não consoantes realmente pronunciadas) e introduzindo a maioria dos acentos que usamos hoje. Portugal antes de 1911 e o Brasil antes de 1943 não tinham grafias oficiais, mas a maioria do pessoal escrevia assim:

> Aquelle auctor vae ha varios annos áquella matta, onde tem escripto á sombra d’uma arvore sobre sciencia, machinas, cyclos astronomicos e outros assumptos.

Estes *c* em *auctor* e *p* em *escripto* e *assumto*, como em muitas outras palavras, não eram pronunciados, mas foram mantidos na escrita, quer em Portugal quer no Brasil, por razões etimológicas. No Brasil antes de 1943 já se encontra *fato*, mas *facto* é de longe mais frequente. Quando é que o *c* de *facto* deixou de ser pronunciado no Brasil é naturalmente uma questão mais difícil de responder. Mas já em 1798 encontramos a palavra escrita sem o *c* nos estatutos de um seminário episcopal de Olinda, Pernambuco (grafia original e negrito meu em todas as citações):

> Sendo pois, como é a Istoria da Igreja uma **fiel narrasão dos fatos**, que servem de provas da nossa crensa […] e a Ciencia Teolojica naõ sendo mais do que a arte de ligar, teser, e **encadear os fatos** que servem, e devem servir de provas de verdade
>   [*Estatutos do Seminario Episcopal de N. Senhora da Grasa da Cidade de Olinda de Pernambuco*, 1798.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=5bFaAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA67&dq=fatos&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj18oOg7_rWAhWDXhoKHbB3Bqk4MhDoAQjfAjAq#v=onepage&q=fatos&f=false)

A palavra *fatos* repete-se quatro vezes. Além disso o autor escreve, por exemplo, *Istoria, ómens* e *Ciencia Teolojica* em vez do normal para época, que seria *Historia, homens* e *Sciencia Theologica*. Isto sugere que *fatos* não é gralha, mas que foi antes o autor que tentou escrever foneticamente, omitindo consoantes mudas.

O mesmo se observa no escritor brasileiro [José de Alencar (1829-77)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_de_Alencar) em [*Ubirajara* (primeira edição de 1874; esta é de 1911)](http://eremita.di.uminho.pt/gutenberg/3/8/4/9/38496/38496-h/38496-h.htm), onde *fato(s)* ocorre oito vezes; eis um exemplo:

> Os historiadores, cronistas e viajantes da primeira época, se não de todo o periodo colonial, devem ser lidos á luz de uma critica severa. É indispensavel sobretudo escoimar os **fatos comprovados** das fabulas a que servia de mote, e das apreciações a que os sujeitavam espiritos acanhados, por demais embuidos de uma intolerancia rispida.

A escrita de Alencar é surpreendente: à parte da acentuação, que é a do século XIX e não a nossa atual, a escrita dele afasta-se da dos seus contemporâneos e aproxima-se extraordinariamente da nossa, principalmente pela supressão de consoantes mudas. O facto de ele escrever *fato* em vez de *facto* indica que ele não pronunciava o *c*.

Mas curiosamente também encontrei *fato* no lugar de *facto* em 1830 num autor português:

> [Prisão] *de facinorosos* etc. quando for feita por Tropa de Linha, Milicias, ou Ordenanças deverá o Comandante dar uma Parte circunstanciada a quem entregar os presos; declarando o ***fato da prisão***, o *dia*, a *hora* e o *logar*, em que ela se efeituou; […] juntamente com a indicação dos nomes das testemunhas, que **presenceárão taes fatos**, ou que tinhão razão de saber da conduta e genero de vida dos ditos presos.
>   [João Crisostomo do Couto e Melo, *Repertorio das Ordens do Dia Dadas ao Exercito Portuguez*, 1830.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=SFdZAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA241&dq=fatos&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixlurL4vrWAhWFVxoKHVL_AAoQ6AEI0QEwGg#v=onepage&q=fatos&f=false)

Também ele suprime consoantes mudas em geral. O seu uso de *fato* em lugar de *facto* indica que também em Portugal havia naquele tempo quem não pronunciasse este *c*.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, @Jacinto! Pode me indicar algum estudo sobre essa mudança de fonia que aconteceu no Brasil? Dada a dimensão do país e a alta diversidade de formas de falar, já presentes na década de 40, quais foram as regiões que serviram de base para a reforma? Como sempre foi uma curiosidade minha, mesmo que não tenha as respostas para essas perguntas, queria saber quais as referências mais indicadas para prosseguir o estudo.

Comment: Infelizmente não sei de estudos sobre a evolução fonética no Brasil. Sei apenas das reformas ortográficas. Mas a maior parte das alterações gráficas poderá até não ter a ver com alterações fonéticas. Muitas das consoantes suprimidas foram sempre mudas. Foram os escritores do renascimento que as meteram nas palavras para as tornar mais parecidas com as suas origens latinas e gregas. A maioria das mudanças fonéticas refletidas na grafia deram-se quer no Brasil quer em Portugal, porque depois de 1943 as grafias dos dois países voltaram a ser praticamente iguais. Palavras como _Fa(c)to_ são raras.

Comment: Vê [como se escrevia antes das reformas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pequeno_dicion%C3%A1rio_comparativo_de_ortografia_em_l%C3%ADngua_portuguesa). Os sotaques dos muitos falantes do português foi mudando de maneiras diferentes nas várias regiões, mas muitas vezes isso não necessita de aterações gráficas. Por exemplo, a grafia _vinte_ serve para muitos sotaques diferentes, _vintchi, vinti, vinte, vint_ (em Lisboa) e _bint_ (muitas pessoas no norte de Portugal).

Comment: Para estudar a evolução fonética no Brasil eu começava pela Wikipédia, [lígua portuguesa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADngua_portuguesa#Hist.C3.B3ria) ou [português brasileiro](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%ADngua_portuguesa#Hist.C3.B3ria) e vê aligações e referências que lá há. Provavelmente já conheces isto, mas é o que eu posso sugerir.

Comment: @felipe.zkn Econtrei uma curiosidade que talvez te interesse. Fernão Lopes (1385-1459), talvez o mais importante escritor português do seu tempo, escrevia *sotilmente*. Isto é possivelmente um exemplo de uma palavra em que os renascentistas introduziram um **b** mudo, para aproximar a palavra à origem latina (*subtilis*). Depois por influência da grafia, começou a pronunciar-se o **b** em Portugal (atualmente *subtilmente*) mas não no Brasil, onde continua *sutilmente*.

Comment: Ah, nãaaaaao!!! Foi a reforma ortográfica de 1911 que introduziu o acento grave?!? Malditos republicanos! :@

Comment: @ANeves Não te conhecia essa aversão ao acento grave. Tens muita sorte já se não escrever *sòmente*, *amàrgamente*, *estùpidamente*, etc.

Comment: @felipe.zkn, descobri umas coisas que acrescentei à resposta. Creio que estarás interessado.

Answer (score 0):

Em minha humilde opinião, a vigência do uso etimológico da língua é mais interessante que a fonética, devido a variação extensa entre os falantes. Deste modo, creio que facto estaria mais etimologicamente correto que fato. O prefixo desta palavra foi mantido no inglês e espanhol em respeito as tradições etimológicas, fora a pronúncia. Não há, a meu ver, lógica em escrever factível e engolir o C em fato. É verdade que poetas e escritores podem dar-se a estas licenças, mas creio que na norma culta elas não deveriam ser feitas.
**Fato**- Cardume de peixes, conjunto de duas peças de roupa, possivelmente do árabe hatu.
**Facto**- do latim *factum*
Fontes:
https://dicionario.priberam.org/facto
https://dicionario.priberam.org/fato

Comment: Também ressuscitarias o *assumpto* e o *theatro*?