# «facto» ou «fato»?

Tags: ortografia, português-europeu, acordo-ortográfico

Depois de ler a [pergunta do nbro](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/3532/153) fiquei na dúvida se em pt-PT se é correto escrever *facto* e/ou *fato*.

Fui fazer uma pesquisa no site e descobri a resposta do Jacinto [Quando “facto” passou a ser “fato”?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/936/153) e pensei, ok continua-se a escrever *facto* em pt-PT ao qual a resposta [Concactenar ou Concatenar?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/209/153) confirmou.

Mas uma pequena pesquisa no google deixou-me confuso sobre o uso de *facto* em pt-PT: [Novo acordo. Duplas grafias, facto, factor, etc.](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/novo-acordo-duplas-grafias-facto-factor-etc/23479).

Pode parecer que as fontes citadas esclarecem bem o assunto, mas eu fiquei na dúvida se em pt-PT se pode escrever *facto*, *fato* ou os dois?

É por causa de se pronunciar o "c", por causa da confusão com [fato (de vestir)](https://www.google.pt/search?q=fato&newwindow=1&client=ubuntu&hs=FeO&channel=fs&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVj_SmwrHOAhVpLcAKHTJRBqsQ_AUICCgB&biw=1628&bih=925) ou os dois?

Comment: Não é pela «homonimidade», de certeza.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pelo novo acordo, as duas :)

De acordo com o dicionário Priberam [Fato, em Portugal, é um *terno*](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/fato).

> fa·to (origem duvidosa, talvez do árabe hatu, peixes, cardume)
>
> Conjunto das peças de roupa. = VESTUÁRIO

Fato, no Brasil, é um facto (*evento*) em Portugal.

> fac·to |ct|
>
> (latim factum, -i, aquilo que se fez, façanha, proeza, acto)

Facto não existe no Brasil.
O novo acordo vem aceitar as duas formas para designar um *evento* mas é importante respeitar a regionalidade:
Em Portugal, facto, no Brasil, fato.

Já se a palavra for usada com o sentido de *terno*, deve sempre ser usada como *fato* já que *facto* é sempre um *evento*.

Comment: Creio que a página do Priberam com a diferença entre os dois é suficiente

Comment: Fato é terno e facto é fato; porém creio que a diferença de grafia reflete uma diferença de pronúncia.

Comment: Em Portugal pronuncia-se o C para um evento, no Brasil nunca se pronuncia o C

Answer (score 3):

As palavras *facto* e *fato* são um caso de dupla grafia, mas simplesmente porque possuem a mesma semântica. A dupla grafia não implica que ambas as formas possam ser usadas tanto no português de Portugal como no português do Brasil. Tal como indicado na resposta do Eduardo Fernandes, deve-se na mesma respeitar a regionalidade: em Portugal o *c* em *facto* é pronunciado, enquanto que no Brasil não é, ficando *fato*.

O Vocabulário Ortográfico Português (VOP) do [Portal da Língua Portuguesa](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/) esclarece logo esta situação e muitas outras. Ao entrar no site verão a barra de pesquisa do VOP no canto superior direito. Pesquisando por [*facto*](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=7358), é indicada a variante do acordo ortográfico "fato" (está em "variante AO").
Em [*fato*](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=3782), observamos a seguinte nota: "Enquanto variante AO, esta forma apenas é aceite no Brasil."

O VOP permite pesquisar por todos estes casos mais bicudos. Por exemplo, o mesmo se aplica a [*contacto*](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/simplesearch.php?action=lemma&lemma=20197&highlight=%5Econtacto$) e [*contato*](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/index.php?action=lemma&lemma=115304), onde muitos portugueses erradamente acabam por escrever *contato*. Como o *c* é pronunciado no português de Portugal, deve-se continuar a escrever *contacto*.

Answer (score 1):

As duas grafias estão corretas, segundo o acordo ortográfico ( alínea c) da Base IV ). Respeitando-se a pronúncia do local. No Brasil, na norma culta, utilizamos facto como estrangeirismo do latim, "de facto", ou em "ipsu facto" ("Fulano cometeu o crime, de facto"). Ou seja, é uma expressão jurídica. Não utilizamos "contacto", por exemplo, mas muitas pessoas usam contactar e até contacto, por aqui. Fato, em Brasil, também pode significar vísceras de animais, como bois e porcos. Em especial, nas regiões nordestinas. Coisa que não levaram em consideração enquanto elaboravam o acordo.